diff-cover changes the ui of an azure devops?
So I was integrating the diff-cover tool in my repository and found that it sometimes gives in a UI format that the line was tested or not tested in the PR -> File.

Any idea how does this work?
Because it is appearing only in some specific folders and not in other folders
I just tried created a change in the folder and pushed it into azure devops and found the UI feature there. But in the diff cover documentation nothing was mentioned about it nor in azure devops documentation (maybe I didn't find).

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
